# AlarmManager repeating every 60 seconds regardless

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Passive.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 50000,
                intent, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 3600000, pendingIntent);
```

That's the code I am using, it originally got the repeat time from a shared setting but even when I hard code it is still repeating every 60 seconds instead of the specified time.

It might be worth mentioning, I am not experiencing this issue on my Tablet, just my HTC One X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone required a full uninstall and re install of the application and now the correct behavior is shown.

Answer (score 1):

use this one before setting alarm--

```
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 50000,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

   //Cancelling the PendingIntent in the AlarmManager If it is already exist

   if(pendingIntent != null) {
       am.cancel(pendingIntent);
      pendingIntent.cancel();  
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am still getting 60 seconds repeats.

Comment: are you changing the UNIQUE ID - 50000 ( for your case ) every next time ?

Comment: No this is kept the same each time. I am only getting this issue on the mobile phone, the tablet is working fine.

Comment: Its quite interesting ...!! Oh I seen your reply...after full uninstall , It started working...good..!!